# Converting image to grayscale on python using scikit

Tags: python, numpy, grayscale

I need to write a function where I convert an image represented as a numpy array to  grayscale. These are some hints below that I received. I am only allowed to use `skimage.color`.

Some relevant hints:

Look at the `skimage.color` subpackage for some useful conversion functions.
By default, `scikit-image` conversion functions will return images with floating-point representations from 0-1. We don't want that; we want integer representations from 0-255. NumPy has a data type for that: `np.uint8` (for 8-bit unsigned integer). To the point above, recall that the `np.array` function takes an optional argument `dtype` to specify the type of the underlying array.

This is what I tried:

```
from skimage.color import rgb2gray

def to_grayscale_uint(img_array):
    original = data.img_array()
    grayscale = rgb2gray(original)
    return grayscale
```

Comment: Note that `img_array` is the thing you're passing into the function. You need to do something with that, not with `data` -- which is not something you gave to the function.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the `skimage` function, and multiply by 255. Then, cast the array into an integer:

```
array *= 255
array.astype(np.uint8)
```